# ubuntu 10.04 stuck on booting due to disk is already mounted

Tags: ubuntu, boot, mount

I replaced a failed hard disk which was mounted to /home. After boot, I logged in as root and replaced the uuid of the /home mount in `/etc/fstab` then rebooted it. Now it gets stuck on boot with the messages:

```
/dev/sda2 is mounted
WARNING: filesystem is mounted..... continue will cause *** SEVERE *** error ...., do you want to continue (Y/n)?
```

But it doesn't accept my 'N' input. It still reacts to <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Del</kbd>. Do you have any idea how I can stop Ubuntu from mounting this one?

Comment: I haven't seen this particular error, but I would boot from a live CD and comment out that line in `/etc/fstab` until you can boot the system.

Comment: Thanks user55325, i did that. The first time booting from cd and somehow the /etc/fstab is completely different to the one I modified. But luckily the second time rebooting from cd, the modified /etc/fstab comes back so I could delete the line and boot into system. Now this problem is fixed. Thanks.